# CVS synchronize/update issue

Tags: version-control, synchronization, cvs

I am using CVS as version control system and facing a strange issue. For some files, I am not able to synchronize or update (using eclipse) because of the following error:

```
"[Project Name]: cvs [update aborted]: cannot create .#lang_en.properties.1.1.2.3.2.7.2.2.2.3.2.1.2.1.2.3.8.1.2.4.6.12.2.3.4.1.4.3.2.6.2.13.4.4.4.1.2.9.2.2.2.1.8.1.8.1.14.1.8.3.26.1.8.1.4.4.6.17.4.2.6.6.6.3.2.2.2.2.10.2.2.2.2.2.2.9.2.7.2.1.4.10.4.2.2.3.4.4.2.2.2.1.2.1.10.2.8.1.6.1.4.1.4.2.6.1.2.1.2.2.4.5.4.1 for copying: File name too long"
```

According to my observation this happens with frequently committed files. What happens is someone in the team commit such a file (which works) but then when some other person in the team try to sync or update, it simply shows 'file name too long' error. I would like to clarify that in example above file name is only "lang_en.properties'.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I have even tried deleting file from cvs and then recreating with same name (that is required), but same revision history appear again. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A file named like `.#<filename>.<revision>` is created when you do a `cvs update` and there are changes made to your checked out file. This is effectively a backup of the version you had, in case the update did something that you didn't want (eg. introduced a conflict that you are having trouble resolving). This allows you to roll back an update.

The simplest way to address this is to remove the local file before doing an update. That way there is no need for CVS to create this backup file.

> According to my observation this happens with frequently committed files.

This is not caused by frequent commits. The revision id will increase sequentially every time you do a commit. eg. `1.1` -> `1.2` -> `1.3` and so on. Extra digits are added when you do branching. For example, if you took a branch off the 1.3 version of the above file then the revision numbers would be `1.3.1.1` -> `1.3.1.2` -> `1.3.1.3` etc.

I don't know how you are working, but your project seems to have introduced an impressive level of branching. Until you address that workflow, you are going to continue coming across this problem almost every time you attempt an update. You have hit the 256 character filename limit which exists on a lot of file systems.